# wordprees multi-site in user panel add filter

Tags: php, multisite

I want to add new custom filter in WordPress network admin

restrict_manage_users for network admin in the user panel[image]

I want a custom filter option not a custom column, i just want to add one filter dropdown with roles

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: hi @vancoder, I have tried restrict_manage_users but this will work in single sites, and I have googled not getting any hooks for filter